# App is crashing and getting Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setMaxLifecycle for Fragment not attached to FragmentManager

Tags: .net, maui

App is crashing in sometime unable to find the root cause.

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setMaxLifecycle for Fragment not attached to FragmentManager FragmentManager{f4b285a in null}}

Provide the resolution of this exception, currently using .NET MAUI 7.0 version with Android.